# What is the corresponding xml for json property?

Tags: c#, json, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I have a JSON property which I need to insert into Oracle DB. I am trying to make XML nodes in C# for the same and then inserting through ExtractValue,XMLSequence concepts in Oracle.

*The **name** property is configured in several language.Each language in Database is identified by objectnumber.Hence you can see en-US has 1 and 3 objectnumber.Arabic has objectnumber 2*

```
"name": {
                "en-US": {
                    "1": "name in english1",
                    "3": "name in english2"
                },
                "ar-SA": {
                    "2": "name in arabic1"
                }
        }
```

Can someone tell what should the XML look like for the above property?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you want it to be.

#### Option 1:

```sql
<name>
  <en-US object-number="1">name in english1</en-US>
  <en-US object-number="3">name in english2</en-US>
  <ar-SA object-number="2">name in arabic1</ar-SA>
</name>
```

#### Option 2:

```sql
<name>
  <language value="en-US">
    <object-number value="1">name in english1</object-number>
    <object-number value="3">name in english2</object-number>
  </language>
  <language value="ar-SA">
    <object-number value="2">name in arabic1</object-number>
  </language>
</name>
```

#### Option 3:

```sql
<names>
  <name>
    <language>en-US</language>
    <object-number>1</object-number>
    <value>name in english1</value>
  </name>
  <name>
    <language>en-US</language>
    <object-number>3</object-number>
    <value>name in english2</value>
  </name>
  <name>
    <language>ar-SA</language>
    <object-number>2</object-number>
    <value>name in arabic1</value>
  </name>
</names>
```

#### Option 4:

```sql
<names>
  <name language="en-US" object-number="1">name in english1</name>
  <name language="en-US" object-number="3">name in english2</name>
  <name language="ar-SA" object-number="2">name in arabic1</name>
</names>
```

There are many, many more varieties that you could use.